# Using Opencv inside Anaconda Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, anaconda

I have compiled and installed anaconda for python 3.5 using the instructions from https://scivision.co/anaconda-python-opencv3/

I have built it.
Now have do i access it, opening terminal and typing python, and then import cv2 gives me no module cv2 found.

I am quite sure i have built it correctly.Do i need to change directory?

Comment: Are you sure that your default python is Anaconda ? What do you read when you type python ?

Comment: hey, it points to anaconda3. Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:53:06)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of building from the source you can install a conda package for opencv.  Try just doing:

```
conda install -c menpo opencv3
```

And then you can try doing `import cv2`.

Unless you plan on changing the opencv source you shouldn't need to build it yourself.  You can simply use a pre-built conda package for it.

Comment: @sridhar Is there an answer to this? I tried what Paul mentioned, but I am facing the same problem as you.

Comment: Ok, yeah, I only tried it on red hat not ubuntu.  I'll try to do it on ubuntu later but if I don't get it done then I'll just delete this answer as it appears that it doesn't work, sorry.